# Setup authentication headers within a test using Quick

Tags: swift, testing, quick-nimble

I'm writing tests for my application with usage of `Quick` and `Nimble`. I've arrived at the part of the tests that require authentication. My app works in a manner that there's a `singleton` named `AuthenticationManager` that has methods for logging in etc. This class also holds the current `authenticationToken`:

```
public var token: String?

public var headers: HTTPHeaders {
    guard let token = token else {
        return ["Accept": "application/json"]
    }

    return [
        "Authorization": "Bearer \(token)",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    ]
}
```

This works in actual usage, however, when this runs with testing, it seems that the value of the `token` variable resets when my test starts. I tried making the login call in the `setUp()` method of my `QuickSpec` file, this however, didn't work. I also tried making te login call within the `it` statement for my test, which also didn't work. This is my code as is right now:

```
override func spec() {

    describe("When a user validates their current password") {
        describe("And the password is correct") {
            it("should validate the user correctly") {
                AuthenticationManager.shared.login(username: "test@example.com", password: "secret") { _ in }
                expect(Validator.validateCurrentPassword("secret")).to(equal(true))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've checked, and the login details are correct, but there's never a token available when the test runs... Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift TDD & async URLSession - how to test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40330692/swift-tdd-async-urlsession-how-to-test)

Comment: ^^ Logging in I presume is an async network task that takes some time to complete. you should use Expectations and do your assertions in the completionHandler once you have a valid response